# Apple mobile device tags

Tags: discussion, tags

We have at least three tags for Apple mobile devices: [ios](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios), [iphone-app](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iphone-app) and [ipad-app](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ipad-app).

I guess [iphone-app](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iphone-app) and [ipad-app](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ipad-app) should be [iphone](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iphone) and [ipad](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ipad) instead — what question about those devices wouldn't be about an app for these devices?

Are separate [iphone](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iphone) and [ipad](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ipad) tags needed at all, or should [ios](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios) be systematically used ([perhaps with [smartphone](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smartphone) or [tablet](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tablet) to distinguish when needed)? After all we have a single tag for [android](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android).

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/App_Store_(iOS)%23Number_of_launched_applications), there are only half as many iPad apps as iPhone apps, so there is a significant difference in availability. Does this justify treating [iphone](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iphone) and [ipad](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ipad) as separate platforms? In that case, is [ios](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios) warranted?

Comment: Related discussion: [Do we really need two separate iphone tags?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1063/60)

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I think should happen:

**Merge**

- [iphone-app](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iphone-app) -> [iphone](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iphone)
- [ipad-app](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ipad-app) -> [ipad](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ipad)

No, we shouldn't ban the [iphone](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iphone) and [ipad](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ipad) tags. There are many requests where an app which runs on one device specifically is needed. For example, I really want a Stack Exchange client on my *iPhone*, and I don't really care if it works on my iPad. Just having [ios](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios) doesn't convey this.

Comment: Are there a lot of apps that run on an iPhone but not on an iPad? If there aren't, then there's no point in having a specific tag, because the distinction is irrelevant.

Comment: @Gilles Yes, and visa versa. I've built some of them.

Comment: Should we use [tag:iphone] and [tag:ipad], or [tag:ios]+[tag:smartphone] and [tag:ios]+[tag:tablet]? I get the feeling that like on SO, the device-specific tags are overused and most questions in fact apply generically to any iOS device.

Answer (score 2):

(As I don’t know much about mobile, I can’t decide if this requirement should be specified in the tags instead of in the title/question only. So in this answer I *assume* that we need tags for this difference.)

If it’s true that there are iOS apps that run on one kind of device only (e.g., iPad *or* iPhone), is this true for other mobile platforms, too?

According to this [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10540646/1591669), it seems to be the case for Android, too.

So maybe, instead of using manufacturer-specific tags like, in case of Apple, [ipad](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ipad)/[iphone](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iphone), we should use *general* tags that can be used for any kind of mobile platform?

For example, [smartphone](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smartphone) and [tablet](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tablet). (Or, if the screen-size is the actual difference here, something like [small-screen](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/small-screen), …?)

So …

- a question asking for apps that have to run on an iPad would be tagged with: [ios](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios), [tablet](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tablet)
- a question asking for apps that have to run on an Android smartphone would be tagged with: [android](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android), [smartphone](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smartphone)

(But again, only if we really need tags to differentiate. Personally, I think we could do without and specify it in the title/body only.)