# Do we really need two separate iPhone tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-merge

Going over today's question, I've [found one](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/16959/185) using the [iphone](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iphone) (× 11) and [iphone-app](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iphone-app) (× 13) – plus additionally [ipad-app](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ipad-app) (× 17). While I can see a reason for the last one to co-exist, I don't see any for two iPhone tags.

Suggestion: Merge with target `iphone-app` and (optionally) make `iphone` a synonym (to prevent the tag from re-appearing).

Comment: I'm in favor of this, we can make it happen if it gets support. The tool for this has a giant "be careful" warning on it, so I'd like to see support *before* I mess something up.

Comment: We've had a bunch of re-tagging and synonymizing over at ASE already. The re-tagging is not the big deal (I'd even volunteer to do that manually – but AFAIK there's a "magic mod tool" doing that automated on a merge). But you're right, I've heard more than once about "crazy things happening" on that – though never anything that couldn't be fixed. So if you're afraid of that automat, I'd re-tag those 11 Qs, and you'd just to make the "empty tag" a synonym then.

Comment: Related discussion: [Apple mobile device tags](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/433/60)

Comment: I still think the `*-app` tags should remain, if for consistency: we also have `web-app` and not `web` :) If you'll remind me of `android` not having the `-app` suffix: that's an OS, not a device.

Comment: I was just coming to meta to start the same discussion. I'm in favor of keeping iphone-app and making iphone a synonym to it, as we have ipad-app as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we seem to have consensus here, merged [iphone](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iphone) → [iphone-app](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iphone-app) and made a synonym.

Comment: Strange that currently they again are 2 separate tags. As per [your answer here](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/434/185) and [RockpaperLizard's suggestion here](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1180/185), I've tried to merge `iphone-app`->`iphone`, but that resulted in an "Ooops" (maybe due to your prior merge?). Let's wait whether the devs contact us back, as an error report has been sent.

Comment: @Izzy It fails because `iphone` is already synonomized to `iphone-app`. If we wanted to switch it, we'd probably have to remove the `iphone` -> `iphone-app` synonym. There's only one tag.

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed that meanwhile. And right, in order to reverse, we'd need to first remove the synonym, then rename the tag, and then re-create the synonym. As it currently stands, I see no clear indication that's what we should do – as opinions seem devided :)

Answer (score 1):

As we already got multiple voices on this, let me sum up an answer from the comments:

- We already had a related discussion here: [Apple mobile device tags](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/433/185)
- We have comparable tags, e.g. [web-apps](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-apps), [google-apps](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-apps)
- We also have related tags without the `-apps` suffix, e.g.: [android](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android), [windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows), [linux](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux)
- Tags without the `-apps` suffix are usually OS tags (as the examples show), while those having the suffix are not – but are rather specific to a vendor or technology

> **Conclusion:** As in this case, the base name again is device specific (which is more close to "vendor specific"), the [iphone-app](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iphone-app) is the one that should remain, and [iphone](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iphone) should be merged with that target and then be made a synonym (to avoid it from being re-created as tag).

For the remaining part (this still leaves us with two iOS specific tags), see the already mentioned discussion in [Apple mobile device tags](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/433/185) – this is a completely different think and was not intended by me to be a topic here; I solely cared about the two iPhone tags in this context.